# ошибка при redirect laravel

Tags: laravel

при возвращении

```
public function login() {
        return view('manager.auth.login'); //пути к файлам через точку(папка.файл)
    }
```

пишет `Route [auth_manager] not defined. (View: /home/e/extremje/sdprepod/study/resources/views/manager/auth/login.blade.php)`

Comment: Так всеж написано. У вас в login.blade.php видимо имеется роут вида href="{{route('auth_manager')}}" но в routes/web.php такой маршрут не описан.

Comment: да, там форрма я не описал action

Comment: но другая проблема

Answer (score 0):

пишет

```
(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
Route [manager/login] not defined.
```

middleware вот такой и роут есть

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('manager/login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

Route::group(['prefix'=>'manager', 'middleware'=>['adminmanager']], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'Admin\DashboardController@dashboard')->name('manager.index');
    Route::get('/login', 'Admin\DashboardController@login');
    Route::get('/users', 'Admin\DashboardController@userstat');
});
```